# add custom path to resources route (only for one action)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have below resource route

```
  resources :listings
```

This will have the path set to `locahost:3000/listings/new`

But how can I customise path to new action(only) to show like
 `locahost:3000/listings/create_your_listing`

or even(better if it can be customised like this)

`locahost:3000/owners/create_your_listing`

Only new action of the resources should be like that and rest as normal.. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First,

**`resources :listings, except: :new`**

This will create `listings` resources except `new`.

next,

**`get "/owners/create_your_listing", to: "listings#new"`**

This will create the missing `new` route for your `listing controller`.

**EDIT:**

This may be the way to achieve custom path:(not tested)

```
scope(path_names: { new: 'create_your_listing'}) do
  resources :listing, path: 'listings'
end
```

[Reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#translated-paths)

Comment: is there a way to do it like 
`resources :listings, path: '/owners/create_your_listing'`??.. Yes the given answer works fine and am already doing that in my app. But just asked this question out of curiosity to know any other better ways

Comment: but you asked it for only new action?

Comment: yes exactly..that will do for all actions. Asked to know weather its possible to do like that for a particular action without adding another line ..

Comment: I think this requires at least two lines because there are two requirements in your question, first need to define route and differentiate the new route.

Comment: @Abhilash, please check my updated answer once. it may be helpful to you.

Comment: yes it works great for the question I asked.. But if its a nested one like this    `resources :listing, path: 'listings' do resource :another end end` then it will put that path to the new action of the another resource aswell..

Comment: yes, I think that should be taken if you need to customize the child new actions too.

Comment: Yes it should be. Thank you.